# Python scraper with POST request doesn't bring any results

Tags: python, post, web-scraping

I've written a script to scrape the "First Name" from a webpage using post request in python. However, Running my script  I get neither any results nor any error. It seems to me that I'm doing things the right way. Hope somebody will point me into the right direction showing me what I'm missing here:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
payload = {'ScriptManager1':'UpdatePanel1|btnProceed','__EVENTTARGET':'','__EVENTARGUMENT':'','__VIEWSTATE':'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','__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':'5629D98D','__EVENTVALIDATION':'/wEdAAekSVFWk+dy9X9XnzfYeR4NT1Z25jJdJ6rNAjXmHpbD+Q8ekkJ2enuXq0jY/CeUlod/njRPjRiZUniYWoSlesZ/+0XiOc/vwjI5jxqS0D5ang1Wtvp3KMocxPzInS3xjMbN+DvxnwFeFeJ9MIBWR693SSiBqUlIhPoALKQ2G08CpjEhrdvaa2JXqLbLG45vzvU=','r1':'rdoPermanent','txtRegistNo':'SRO0394294','__ASYNCPOST':'true','btnProceed':'Proceed'}
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.post("https://www.icaionlineregistration.org/StudentRegistrationForCaNo.aspx", params=payload, headers=headers).text
tree = html.fromstring(response)
item = tree.xpath('//div[@class="div_input_place"]/input[@id="txt_name"]/@value')
print(item)
```

URL is given in my script and the reg number to get the "First Name" is "SRO0394294". The xpath I've used above is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the __EVENTTARGET field is empty, it may be needed in order to submit your request. You can find the value to set with the form submit button in most cases.

Also since the __VIEWSTATE is always regenerating upon requests you'll need to grab it. You can do firstly a GET request, save the __VIEWSTATE input and then do a POST request with the previous __VIEWSTATE value.

Comment: Thanks Adrien Brignon, for your answer. I did according to the form request parameter generated in the chrome developer tool.

Answer (score 0):

`__VIEWSTATE` input is always changing. this input could be used to prevent the registration form from bots